Is a surjective closed immersion $Y \to X$ an isomorphism when $Y$ is reduced?
$\require{ams}$ Suppose we have an affine scheme $X = \text{Spec }R$, a closed subset $S \subseteq X$ and a closed immersion $\iota: Y \to X$ with image $\iota(Y) = S$. In particular this means $\iota: Y \to S$ is a homeomorphism of topological spaces. Furthermore, $Y$ is a reduced (affine) scheme (i.e. $O_Y(U)$ is a reduced ring for all open $U \subseteq Y$, or equivalently, the stalk $O_{Y,y}$ is a reduced ring for any $y \in Y$).
Can we conclude anything about the isomorphicity of $\iota$ (onto S)?
I have already found a question that talks about the case where $X$ is reduced, but not when $Y$ is. Any help would be appreciated!

No. Consider $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x) \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^2)$ for $k$ a field. Then this is surjective (both are single points) but not an isomorphism.
In general, for any scheme $X$ there is always the closed immersion of the reduction $X_{red}\to X$, which is always surjective, and only an isomorphism if $X$ is reduced. So any non-reduced scheme $X$ is a counterexample - the one above is just one of the simplest ones.
